# how can i get a man page for a header

Tags: command-line, manpage

Just as the title, I want to `man` a header like `pthread.h`, but it cannot be reached on Ubuntu. However, I used this feature from a computer which has Fedora as OS, but I don't know how to configure it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install this package: [`manpages-posix-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/manpages-posix-dev). It's in multiverse -- be sure to have that enabled first.

Then just use `$ man pthread.h` for the manpage.

For other queuries like where some file or manpage is, just search the contents of packages at http://packages.ubuntu.com, like [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pthread.h&mode=filename&suite=quantal&arch=any) and you'll find the appropriate package.